# XSLT: Retain span between xml tag after transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple xml and xsl which is as follows:

**XML**

```
<p><span>a</span> <span>b</span></p>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:variable name="output">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//p"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$output" />

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space(.)) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Please note the space between the closing of first span tag and opening of second span tag.

Currently the output of this transformation gives:

**Output**

```
ab
```

Is there a way in XSLT where in we can retain the space between the span tag after transformation.

**Desired Output**

```
a b
```

Tried specifying **xml:space="preserve"** in both p and span template match tags. It just puts a lot of space.

Also my scenario doesn't give me option to add a place holder tag which could have been translated to empty whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of any other overriding templates I would expect that fragment of XSLT to produce your desired result, *unless* you have an `xsl:strip-space` instruction at the top level of your stylesheet.  If you have one of those declarations then you should remove it, or at least add

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="p"/>
```

to countermand the `strip-space` for `p` elements specifically.

Comment: Your are absolutely right, there was a global strip-space in between the code which I didn't notice. Your suggestion did help. Thanks.